# Is it possible to have a Group without any elements inside it?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, category-theory, monoid

I know that any set with just one single element forms a group. The single element satisfies all the axioms. However, similarly to how we have an empty set, which is nevertheless still a set, is it possible to have a sort of "empty" group that would "vacuously" satisfy the group axioms?

I have looked at the Wikipedia page for Group, however I could not find an explicit statement that said that a "0" group can not exist.

If an "empty" group does not in fact exist, then I am confused as to why an "empty" category can exist. It would seem like sometimes you can in fact have "empty" trival objects, and then in other areas of mathematics you can not. I would really appreciate an intuitive discussion as to why that could be?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Downvote. Literally no effort on your part. You just need to look at the axioms.

Comment: I see.. I'm sorry to ask this dumb question then. However I am still curious as to why the axioms for the definition of a category allow for there to be an "empty" category. Why are the axioms for groups stricter? What will "break" if don't explicitly require groups to have an identity. Would it be very wrong if the axioms for a group stated that "if a group has some elements, then it must also have an identity element"

Comment: not much will break if you add one exceptional empty group, although its nice that the category of groups has a zero object. If you change the definition that would no longer be the case.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Thank you for your comment

Comment: @user2407334 If you altered the definition of a group that way, a lot of useful theorems would probably go away. The most important one I can think of right now is the fact that it's possible to construct a homomorphism between any two groups $G$ and $H$ (by sending all elements of $G$ to the identity element of $H$). This alteration also makes the concept more complicated. You'd be paying two costs for no benefit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty group cannot exist, because one of the group axioms explicitly asks for the existence of an identity element.

Comment: Is it bad to ask why axioms for a "group" explicitly require there to be an identity element, however the axioms for the definition of a category do not have a similar restriction? That is part of the confusion for me.

Comment: Short answer to your question-in-a-comment: Categories and groups are different mathematical objects, with different theories, different properties, different applications. To get the long answer, ask a new question. Generally speaking, questions-in-comments are pretty useless on a stack exchange site, no-one will see them.

Answer (score 5):

No, by definition a group must contain an identity element.